# how to handle Java heap space error in H2

Tags: java, h2

I have stored a object in H2 database which contains blob.Which is nothing but a File of size more than 450 MB. I am able to store the object successfully in H2 database but getting heap space error while running select statement for this table using H2 console.

I have tried to increase the heap size but could not be able to increase more than 2 GB as I am getting error  as "could not preserve this much space".

Please suggest.

Comment: Use a 64bit JVM then you can increase the heap beyond 2GB

Comment: Yes I am using 64 bit version and it's allowing me to set more than 2 GB but while I start H2 databse it's giving "could not be able to preserve this much of space" at the same time my main memory is having more than 4 GB free space

Comment: When you run the console you're allocating this much heap space? Doesn't seem right, that you'd need that much. Please include *specific* information with what you're running, and how.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right object type, as well as functions for accessing / reading the data in the large object? Take a look at: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#large_objects